# How to get async await / promise based response

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

So I have a code as below. There is a function that calls 2 axios requests to fetch some sample API data.

```
function fetch_records(){
  var api_url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo"
  var api_url2 = "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt"

  axios.get(api_url1)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('Data1 received: ',response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })

  axios.get(api_url2)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('Data2 received: ',response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

And then I want to run this function fetch_records() as below

```
console.log('Script started');
fetch_records();
console.log('Script ended');
```

So that the output should be

```
Script started
... api response data ...
Script ended
```

But because Javascript is asynchronous, it always gives output as below

```
Script started
Script ended
... api response data ...
```

I belive async/await or promise is used to achieve the response I want but I am not sure how to use that exactly.

Comment: this how JS async call works. If you want data then use promise.all a below

Comment: `Javascript is asynchronous` no it isn't ... but AJAX calls are

Comment: Since you already mentioned `async`/`await`, did you actually try using it? Yes, it is the right tool, learn about it! Please show us your approach and ask a specific question about what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `async/await` keywords, but remember JS always is JS.

```
async function fetch_records() { // a async function
  var api_url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo"
  var api_url2 = "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt"

  // waterfall way
  const data1 = await axios.get(api_url1); // await
  console.log('Data1 received: ', data1);

  const data2 = await axios.get(api_url2); // await
  console.log('Data2 received: ', data2);

  // parallel way
  // const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
  //   axios.get(api_url1),
  //   axios.get(api_url2)
  // ]);
  // console.log(data1, data2);
}

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Script started');
    await fetch_records(); // await a async function (Thenable object)
    console.log('Script ended');
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function to return promises:

```
function fetch_records() { 
 var api_url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo"
 var api_url2 = "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt"

const promise1 = axios.get(api_url1)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log('Data1 received: ',response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})

const promise2 = axios.get(api_url2)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log('Data2 received: ',response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

 return [promise1, promise2];

}
```

now use promise.all :

```
Promise.all(fetch_records()).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response[0], response[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fetch_records() {
  var api_url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo"
  var api_url2 = "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt"

  return [
    axios.get(api_url1),
    axios.get(api_url2)
  ]
}

console.log('Script started');
Promise.all(fetch_records()).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  console.log('Script ended');
})
```

`Promise.all` will wait till all promises are resolved, [more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetch_records() {
  var api_url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(api_url1)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Data1 received: ", response);
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Use with Async/Await :

```
async function getData() {
   let data = await fetch_records();
   console.log("Fetch Records :: ", data);
}
```